# Exception while running connectorz Executor framework

Tags: java, frameworks, jboss6.x, connector, jca

I am trying to run [connectorZ](https://github.com/AdamBien/connectorz) [JCA 1.6](https://jcp.org/en/jsr/detail?id=322) Executor implementation,
For that I downloaded [Zip from github](https://github.com/AdamBien/connectorz/archive/master.zip) and try to execute the client,
([Work Manager](http://connectorz.adam-bien.com/): JCA implementation of java.util.concurrent.Executor)

I am able to run the application in Eclipse, (after solving some of dependency issues)
the jsp page loading fine with the link "Execute 5 blocking tasks",
when I click on particular link I am getting below Exception:

```
Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException
    at org.connectorz.threading.ThreadsResource.overload(ThreadsResource.java:72) [classes:]
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method) [rt.jar:1.7.0_40]
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:57) [rt.jar:1.7.0_40]
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43) [rt.jar:1.7.0_40]
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:606) [rt.jar:1.7.0_40]
```

Here the Issues is executorFactory is null, I am not sure about jndi_name "**jca/workmanager**".

```
@Resource(name="jca/workmanager")
WorkExecutorFactory executorFactory; //NPE at executorFactory(not injecting).
```

Whether I am missing any configuration related to jndi or any resource file?
How can I solve this Issue?

Answer (score 0):

Accessing a JCA Module from another deployed module needs three steps:

1. Deploy the JCA Module to your application server
2. Create a Connection-Pool for the formerly deployed JCA Module
3. Create a JNDI Entry for the JCA Module which specifies which Connection-Pool to use.

In your case I think you didn't do step 2 and 3.

The JNDI-Name for the Connection-Pool can be choosen free, but the JNDI-Name for the third step must be the same as the one given by your @Resource-Annotation (= jca/workmanager).

How you execute the above steps depends on your ApplicationServer.

Please note that currently there is a bug containing the @Size-Annotation in the ConnectionFactory class of the RAR module. For Fixing this just comment it out.

Comment: I am able to deploy JCA module(RAR) in my server, when I try to execute client it's getting same exception (java.lang.NullPointerException at WorkExecutorFactory instance of ThreadsResource class) ,
could you please explain the way to deploy and run work-manager in connectorz using JBoss EAP 6.1.